# Java Native JPA Implementation/ORM

Tags: java, orm

Does Java have a Standard ORM built-in or if not, has Oracle mentioned any plans to create or not create one?

It would be nice to be able to create a full enterprise web application without using a 3rd party framework like Hibernate...

Comment: This is not off-topic, stop being rep-greedy. I'm not asking for an opinion, I'm asking if Oracle/Sun created an ORM in the Java API or not (or if they've announced any plans to/not to). It's a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "native" implementation of JPA. You can try [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/). It is an Apache project I think it is as close as you can get on the "native" way.

I don't think there will be a reference implementation for it because there is no need for one. Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA they are all open source. What more do you want?

I recommend Hibernate or EclipseLink though.